# How do I apply a a rule if the div is contained in a a certain container

Tags: css, less

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="phoo">
    <div class="thing">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="thing">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide "hello" when the class is bar.

I thought I needed to add a & sign like this but it doesn't work. It's frustrating because I know the documentation is there somewher, but I just don't know what to call this situation.

```
.wrapper {
  .bar & {
    .thing {
      display:none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem with your & is that where you place the & sign, the parent class will be placed. So your code would output: `.bar .wrapper .thing {}`

Answer (score 4):

```css
.wrapper > .bar > .thing
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="phoo">
    <div class="thing">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="thing">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Worked for me.